# How to make an image slider as autoplay?

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, slider

I have 3 images which is sliding manually but i want to make it as auto slide. The structure of my code

```
<div id="slideshow">
  <div class="our-clients-block col-6-tablet clear">
    <h3 class="h3">Our Factory</h3>
    <input type="radio" name="clients" id="client-tab-1" class="client-tab-radio client-tab-radio-1 none" checked>
    <label class="client-tab-label client-tab-label-1" for="client-tab-1" onclick><span class="none">Client Tab</span></label>
    <div class="client-tab client-tab-1">
     <img alt=""  src="img/f2.jpg">
    </div>
    <input type="radio" name="clients" id="client-tab-2" class="client-tab-radio client-tab-radio-2 none">
    <label class="client-tab-label client-tab-label-2" for="client-tab-2" onclick><span class="none">Client Tab</span></label>
    <div class="client-tab client-tab-2">
    <img alt=""  src="img/f3.jpg">
    </div>
    <input type="radio" name="clients" id="client-tab-3" class="client-tab-radio client-tab-radio-3 none">
    <label class="client-tab-label client-tab-label-3" for="client-tab-3" onclick><span class="none">Client Tab</span></label>
    <div class="client-tab client-tab-3">
      <img alt=""  src="img/f1.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

I have tried something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#slideshow img:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() { 
  $('#slideshow img:first')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
},  3000);
```

it worked as autoplay but its position has been changed to somewhere else. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Its CSS issue. Check css of the image and div.

Example of CSS:

```
#slideshow { 
    margin: 50px auto; 
    position: relative; 
    width: 240px; 
    height: 240px; 
    padding: 10px; 
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 
}

#slideshow > div { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 10px; 
    left: 10px; 
    right: 10px; 
    bottom: 10px; 
}
```

Comment: I have tried this but i have a css already. i'm just trying to make this autoslide @user2998756